# Determining if subspaces are equal, or if one is a subspace of the other.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose A is the column space of B, which is given by 
$B = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 2 \\
1 & 2\\
0 &3 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$. Suppose C is the column space space of D, which is given by $D = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0\\
0 & 0  \\
-1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$. How would I determine whether A = B, A is a subspace of B, or if B is a subspace of A? Then, how could I find the dimension of the subspace that is the intersection of A and B?

I do not think either column vector of D is in the span of B, and vice versa. Thus, is the 0 vector the only vector in the intersection?

Thanks!

Comment: Please use MathJax for proper formatting.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Formatting fixed. Thanks!

Comment: You say “do not think” that the two subspaces have more than the trivial intersection. Why not?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to row-reduce a matrix of all column vectors from $B$ and $D$ to show which vectors are linear combinations of the others.  The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 2 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 1 & 0\\
0 &3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$ reduces to $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$, which means the set of all four column vectors is linearly independent, so the column spaces of $B$ and $D$ intersect only at the zero vector.

If instead we used $B$ and $F=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&11\\0&9\\-1&3\end{bmatrix}$, we'd row-reduce $\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 2 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 1 & 11\\
0 &3 & 0 & 9\\
0 & 1 & -1 & 3\\
\end{bmatrix}$ to get $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 5\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$. In this matrix we see $(\text{column }4) = 5(\text{column } 1) + 3(\text{column } 2)$. This relationship holds in the original matrix, i.e. 
$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\11\\9\\3\end{bmatrix} = 5 \begin{bmatrix} -1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} + 3 \begin{bmatrix} 2\\2\\3\\1\end{bmatrix} $. So the column spaces of $B$ and $F$ intersect at $\mathrm{span}\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1\\11\\9\\3\end{bmatrix}\right)$.

In general, you'd row-reduce $B$ and $D$ separately to find a set of column vectors which form the basis of their column spaces (in your example it's easy to see the vectors are LI so both column spaces have dimension $2$). If you then reduce a matrix of the combined column vectors, the number of rows with leading $1$s gives you the dimension of the combined column space (in your example, $4$), so you can work out the dimension of the intersection (in your example, $2+2-4=0$).